# Error in MySQL to import file.txt

Tags: mysql

Hello everybody i have some question about MySQL. I want to import text file to inside fields,they come error:

```
[ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/home/nasimjon/Documents/id_site.txt' (Errcode: 2)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/nasimjon/Documents/id_site.txt' INTO table ...
```

if you use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/nasimjon/Documents/id_site.txt' table ...
```

Comment: Whatever the come error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table Site' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a file located on the client-side, you have to use the **LOCAL** keyword :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'/home/nasimjon/Documents/id_site.txt' ...
```

Comment: I have some id they have so many integer. I want to just put text file , not set all of those numbers. That's way i need it.